# Elixir: Difference between Supervisor, GenServer and Application

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor

I was practicing with this example.
https://github.com/kwmiebach/how-to-elixir-supervisor

I followed the instruction and got the idea of how it works, but I can't understand how Supervisor, GenServer and Application are different to each other exactly.

Can someone explain how these 3 are different and when they should be used?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, these are all "OTP Design Principles" (and supported with a standard library), they are all wrappers (or better put, abstractions) on top of basic Erlang primitives like processes. This means they are *not* the only way to program in Erlang (hence Elixir), but they're shared by the community and backed by decades of battle-tested real-world systems. So you *should* use them too.

---

`GenServer` is usually considered as the basic *runtime* building block for applications implemented with Elixir. Although in fact it's a wrapper around the lower-level Erlang Process primitives, however, `GenServer` provides many advanced features like debugging and tracing in a standard interface. Basically, you would usually use (many) `GenServer` to manage state and "do actual work" in your application.

---

[`Supervisor`, as the documentation suggests](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html):

> A supervisor is a process which supervises other processes, which we refer to as child processes. Supervisors are used to build a hierarchical process structure called a supervision tree.

So in a sense, it "manages" `GenServer`s, but also other `Supervisor`s (and other Erlang Process abstractions, if they implement proper interface). You usually don't put any custom logic in `Supervisor` modules, partly because their role is very focused - just manage child processes' life cycles. But also to make it less prone to errors (introduced by your changes).

Say it in another way, `Supervisor` doesn't do any actual "work" for your application, it's just used to "layout" the architecture of a system.

---

Compared to the others, `Application` is *not* necessarily a "runtime concern", [as the Erlang documentation suggests](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html):

> ... make the code into an application, that is, a component that can be started and stopped as a unit, and which can also be **reused** in other systems.

So `Application` is really about bundling stuff into a "unit", and real systems are usually composed of many such units - for example whenever you run some Elixir code, there is also an `"elixir" Application` which runs several processes such as `elixir_code_server`:

[image: Elixir Runtime]

More importantly, `Application` is THE way to share (reuse) code in OTP design principles. When you define an application, it *can* have a "root supervisor", which is started together with the application. Or it can also just have functional codes, without running any processes at all, like [a JSON library](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason/blob/master/mix.exs#L8). Either way, to reuse code across different systems, they need to be packaged into `Application`s.

---

Finally, I'd suggest give this a read: https://ferd.ca/the-zen-of-erlang.html it explained (at least for me) how we go from basic (Erlang) processes, to supervisors (and supervision tree), and a little bit of OTP applications. (And how we should approach programming within BEAM)

Comment: Where's that screenshot from ?

Comment: @JKJ https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/debugging.html#observer